# Nullpointerexception in Google Maps fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How come I get a nullpointerexception on this line: `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`?

```
public class Fragment01 extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);


LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title("Sydney")
    .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
    .position(sydney));

return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
  super.onDestroyView();
   Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
  FragmentTransaction ft =     getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.remove(fragment);
  ft.commit();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map is not set so it is null, you have to initialize your variable

Comment: Thank you! So, how do I set the map? The layout contains only a map fragment.

Comment: Usually you can do something like this: map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); where map is the id of the fragment map

Comment: Please accept the response if it's ok for you. Thanks